# Did Ram become the Bit in the Recognizer?

Tags: tron

In Tron the character Ram is seen to fade away inside of the damaged recognizer that Flynn restored. Shortly after this a Bit arrives to accompany Flynn on his trip to the I/O tower. Did Ram become this Bit, in a sense living on after death (albeit in a reduced fashion), or was the Bit always there but it coincidentally did not come out until Ram expired?

Comment: Could be the bit was a standard accessory for recognizers, but it didn't have the power to activate the bit until Ram's energy fed into it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always though it was [Clu](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Clu)'s bit, he lost it when is tank was destroyed :

> As Clu attempted to get away, he was ambushed by a Recognizer. Clu fired at it and successfully destroyed it, but its remains rained down on Clu's tank. The vehicle went out of control as the blast radius lifted the tank to its side and crashed into one of the many walls in the maze of the memory sector.

And from [Flynn's Recognizer](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Flynn%27s_Recognizer) article on Tron Wikia.

> In the novelization, the pieces that form this Recognizer are the remains of one of the Recognizers Clu destroyed in the beginning of the movie.

So I assume it just followed Flynn when he saw him, thinking it was Clu.

Answer (score 5):

The Bit appears to be linked to Clu, and hence nothing to do with Ram, who by this point had completely derezzed.

> *The Bit edged forward, trying for a better look at Flynn. It came a
> little farther. Flynn whirled on it, holding up his hand with thumb
> and forefinger out as if it were a gun. “Okay; hold it right there!”
> He wondered what eerie new development the System was about to toss
> his way.*
>
> *It was a glittering, faceted shape, nearly a sphere. **The Bit cringed
> timidly, then saw Flynn’s face. Thinking it had found Clu again, it
> came closer. The Bit expanded into a spiky green star and, overjoyed,
> shouted, “Yeah!”***
>
> <sub><sup>[Tron: A Novel](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON_(novelization))</sup></sub>

and

> *“Absolutely,” replied the Bit energetically. “Yup!” **It had missed Clu
> terribly since taking refuge in the Reco he’d destroyed with his tank.
> It was deliriously happy to be back with him,** but didn’t understand
> why he had become so forgetful. “Only yes and no,” Flynn ruminated,
> brows knit. Then it dawned on him. “You’re a Bit!”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Tron: A Novel](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON_(novelization))</sup></sub>